# Problems with socket.io and Nodejs controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Hello guys i have a strange problem

in chatController.js

```
var io = socketIO(server)
```

and server exported from index.js

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(config.port,()=> console.log(`Listening on port ${ config.port }`))
module.exports = server
```

and in my routes

```
router.get('/' , chatController.index)
```

my controller class

```
class chatController extends controller {
index(req,res){
    console.log('Request')
    res.render('/')   
    io.on('connection' , (socket)=>{
        console.log(socket.id)
    })}
```

when i request to / for first time everythings ok
but when i request for second time io.on function make 2 same socket for request

---

my Terminal log

### [terminal picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdvMT.jpg)

i have three socket.id in third request
can u help me ?
thanks

Comment: you need to disconnect before calling the api again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put
    `io.on('connection',(socket)=>{})` inside any request handler(controller);
You can use it in index.js.

```
 const server = http.createServer(app);
    var io = socketIO(server)
    server.listen(config.port,()=> console.log(`Listening on port ${ config.port }`))
    io.on('connection' , (socket)=>{
            console.log(socket.id)
    module.exports = server;
```

Or write module which is independent of any controller logic something like 
 this:

```
 // IOConnection.js
    module.exports =   function(io) {
     io.on('connection' , (socket)=>{
         console.log(socket.id)
     })
    }



 var IOConnection = require('./IOConnection.js')
    const server = http.createServer(app);
    var io = socketIO(server);
    IOConnection(io);
    server.listen(config.port,()=> console.log(`Listening on port ${ config.port }`))

module.exports = server;
```